# Why is limit price order been executed with a worse price?

Tags: equities, market-data, market-microstructure, limit-order-book

recently I was trying to analysis the message data from NASDAQ ITCH data, but I find a problem with a type of message called "Executed With Price Message".

For example, first there is an Add Order Message, place a limit price ask order at price 10 dollar, then there is an Executed With Price Message tell that limit order has been executed at price 9.99 dollar which is 1 cent worse than the limit order. Could someone explain to me why this happens.

Comment: It could have been a buy order in which case it was price improved...

Comment: It just sounds like you are dramatically wrongly building your order book.

Comment: I was trying to build limit order book base on the messages stream, do you know where I goes wrong?